# How to change color for mismatch words in HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlighting

I have a `span` and an `input` field; I want to change the color of the text in `span` when I enter that text in input field.

Following is my code:

i want, if i type wrong word then that word will red in span

```js
var i=0;
var idx=0;
document.body.onkeydown = function(e){

    if(e.keyCode == 32 )
    
{
highlight();
}
}
function highlight() {
  var str= document.getElementById("pera").innerText.split(' ');
  var text= str[i];
  var wrdl = text.length;
  var inputText = document.getElementById("pera");
  var innerHTML = inputText.innerText;
 var pretext = innerHTML.slice(0, idx);
 var postext = innerHTML.slice(idx+text.length);
 
  if ( idx >= 0 && text!="")
    {      
var highlightedText = pretext; 
   highlightedText += "<span class='highlight'>";
  highlightedText += text;
  highlightedText += "</span>";
  highlightedText += postext;
     document.getElementById("pera").innerHTML=highlightedText;
    }
 
i++;
idx += parseInt(text.length+1);
}
```

```css
.highlight
{
background-color:yellow;

}
```

```html
<span id="pera">This paragraph is a value of span</span>
</br>
<input type="text" id ="inp" onfocus="highlight();" />
```

Comment: Where is your jquery code??

Comment: @priya_singh do you see a mention of jQuery?

Comment: @priya_singh This can be accomplished using pure JS. Why does he need jQuery?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show what you've tried. Also, read the help section on how to ask questions.

Comment: @Toastrackenigma ya... but where is javascript code?? what he had tried???

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: i want to compare the value of span text and input text, one by one if both words aren't same then javascript change the color span's specific word,,  and i have have no idea about js code,, what is choose, split()?? array?? etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should highlight in green the parts that match, and in red the parts that do not.

It works by finding the index of the first occurrence of the text that the user entered, and adding the starting and ending `<span>` tags around it.

```js
function highlight() {

  const text = "This paragraph is a value of span"; //The actual text to compair the value against

  var value = document.getElementById("in").value; //The input value

  var startingIndex = text.indexOf(value); //The string index where the value begins in the paragraph
  
  if (startingIndex!=-1) { //If the value is within the text
  
    var endingIndex = startingIndex+value.length; //The string index where the value ends is just the length of the value added to the starting index
  
    var highlightedText = text.slice(0,startingIndex); //The text from the beginning to the start of the highlight
    highlightedText += "<span style=\"color:green;\">"; //Add the HTML which will cause the highlight
    highlightedText += text.slice(startingIndex,endingIndex); //Add the text to highlight
    highlightedText += "</span>"; //Add the HTML which will cause the end of the highlight
    highlightedText += text.slice(endingIndex); //Add the remaining text
    
    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = highlightedText; //Set the HTML of the paragraph to be the new, highlighted string that we made.
    
  }
  
}
```

```html
<span id="para" style="color:red"><span style="color:green">This paragraph is</span> a value of span</span><br><br>
    
<input type="text" id="in" value="This paragraph is" oninput="highlight()">
```

Comment: no i want to compare word one by one, if words are no equal then change color in span

Comment: Well, you haven't explained that either in your question, and now here as well. If the words are not equal to... *what*? How are the colours defined? I'm sure it makes sense to you, but if you want help then you need to explain it properly.

Comment: i want like a typing tutor. compare words if they are then colored it green else colored it red,

Comment: I get what you're aiming at now! My code should do that for you. If this answer works, don't forget to click the checkmark next to it on the left-hand side :D

Answer (score 1):

#### This is A simple way to do to this task without using regexp. Now you can every time use only replaceColor function for any string object.

```js
    String.prototype.replaceColor = function(search, replacement, replaceContainer) {
        var target = this;
        var toReplace = target.split(search).join(replacement);
        replaceContainer.html(toReplace);
    };

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        var container = $('#para');
        var str = container.text();


        $('#in').on('keyup', function() {
            var replacement = "<span class='redText'>" + this.value +"</span>";
            str.replaceColor(this.value, replacement, container);
        });
    });
```

```css
    .redText {
        color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="para">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>

<input type="text" id="in" value="" placeholder="input text"/>
```

Comment: 1. i want compare word unlike single character, if two words equal then green color and if not equal then red color. 2. paragraph color black at starting point. 3. needed code in pure javascript unlike java jQuery, AJEX

Comment: No problem dear Lakhvir I can help you but now I am working I will write a new code with features like you want :)

Answer (score 0):

## [`new RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

The following example uses [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) created from the `value` of the `<input>` on [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).

> Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings.

If the ([case sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_searching_with_flags)) `value` is matched by [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), we [capture](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_parenthesized_substring_matches) the match, and wrap it in `<span>` tags, which have a CSS rule dictating that they should be `color: red`.
With the `"g"` (global) flag set, `replace()` acts on every matched string, instead of only the first if this flag is omitted.

> The `replace()` method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

We then set the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) of the `<p>` to the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) of the `<p>` with all the matched text wrapped in `<span>`s.

> The `Element.innerHTML` property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants.
>   ...
>   This property provides a simple way to completely replace the contents of an element.
>
> ---
>
> `textContent` returns the concatenation of the `textContent` property value of every child node, excluding comments and processing instruction nodes. This is an empty string if the node has no children.

Finally we use [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with its optional second argument as the `value` of the `<input>`; if the `<input>` has a `value`, anything not typed correctly will be colored red, otherwise will remain the fallback text color.

> When a second argument is present: If the second argument evaluates to `true`, add specified class value, and if it evaluates to `false`, remove it.

```js
const para = document.querySelector( "p" );
document.querySelector( "input" ).addEventListener( "input", function() {
  const input = this.value,
        content = para.textContent;
  para.innerHTML = input ? content.replace(
      new RegExp( "(" + input + ")", "g" ), // search for "input.value"
      "<span>$1</span>" // replace with "<span>input.value</span>"
    ) : content;
  para.classList.toggle( "active", input );
}, false );
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #444;
}
p.active {
  color: darkred;
}
span {
  color: darkgreen;
}
input {
  padding: .5em;
  vertical-align: .1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<label>Change the color of this text: <input type="text"></label>
```