# Accessing and coloring specific text within HTML table cell without using RegExp

Tags: javascript, html

This is a portion of my table:

**index.php**

```
<tr>
    <th>data_uwr</th>
    <td>-1.413\-5.113</td>
    <td>-3.314\-3.650</td>
    <td>-0.001\-0.010</td>
    <td>-1.052\-1.052</td>
    <td>-1.052\-1.052</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, each of the cells has 2 numbers separated by a backslash. **Can I somehow apply different colors to each of these 2 numbers?** For example, in first `<td>`, -1.413 would be green and -5.113 would be red.

This is what I tried to do but it did not work:

**index.js**

```
// This is how I get the row. What this code does is it colors the entire cell - everything in the cells becomes green.
mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'green';

// Then I tried splitting cell content into an array (of strings), and coloring each string - each number became a string
let test = mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].firstChild.textContent.split('\\');
test[0].fontcolor('green');
```

I used this [fontcolor()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fontcolor.asp) method but it did not work. Since *String* is not a DOM element, I am not sure how I can color it.

**Edit**: My question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625402/how-to-color-portion-of-text-using-css-or-jquery). I do not intend to use RegExp mainly because it is very hard to define a pattern in my case. There are thousands of numbers that I cannot predict. The colorization is done based on formulas (which I did not include here for simplicity).

**Edit 2**:

This is a snippet of code from my function (you may think that some variables are not declared etc., but note that this a cut-out snippet for simplicity purposes):

```
for (let numOfRunsToCompute = 2; numOfRunsToCompute < runs; numOfRunsToCompute++) {
    let baseline = mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[1].firstChild.textContent;
    let newCellValue = mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].firstChild.textContent;
    let splitBaseline = baseline.split('\\');
    let splitNewCellValue = newCellValue.split('\\');

    for (let i = 0; i < splitBaseline.length; i++) {
        let numBaseline = Math.abs(splitBaseline[i]);
        let numNewCellValue = Math.abs(splitNewCellValue[i]);

        if (numBaseline >= flagNum) {
            let greenCell = numBaseline * greenNum;
            let orangeCell = numBaseline * orangeNum;

            if (numNewCellValue >= 0 && numNewCellValue < greenCell) {
                // For example, this is where I need to apply those colors
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'green';
            } else if (numNewCellValue >= greenCell && numNewCellValue <= orangeCell) {
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'orange';
            } else {
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'red';
            }
        } else {
            let greenCell = numBaseline + greenOrangeWorse;
            let orangeCell = greenCell + greenOrangeWorse;

            if (numNewCellValue >= 0 && numNewCellValue < greenCell) {
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'green';
            } else if (numNewCellValue >= greenCell && numNewCellValue < orangeCell) {
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'orange';
            } else {
                mainTable.rows[rowNumber].cells[numOfRunsToCompute].style.color = 'red';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To put it simply: what this code does is basically some pre-formatting and essentially determining which color to give a particular cell. But in this specific case, I need to color a particular piece of information in the cell, not entire cell.

Comment: You could start by modifying the original table *by hand* (that is, not using javascript) to display the colors you want; *then* you could look into how to make that happen via javascript.

Comment: Yeah but the thing is that I cannot modify the table by hand.

Comment: What's your goal? You want to make every first number green and every second number red in every `<td>` via Javascript?

Comment: No. The actual goal is to colorize a cell based on some formulas (which I did not include here). The question is how do I color specific text inside HTML `<td>`. I wanted to ask it simple.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color portion of text using css or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24625402/how-to-color-portion-of-text-using-css-or-jquery)

Comment: @HereticMonkey read my edit and edited question title

Comment: Take your pick; there are a few dozen questions out there: [JavaScript: How to change color to only part of the string in an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45233743/215552), [How to change color for mismatch words in HTML using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45184143/215552), [Change the color of a text in div using jquery contains](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17232820/215552), [HTML: Changing colors of specific words in a string of text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4622808/215552)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, you can't style a specific section of text.  You'll be forced to manipulate the DOM, since you said you don't have access to change the source HTML.  Try this:

```
var color1 = 'green'; // or '#008000'
var color2 = 'red';   // or '#ff0000'
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for (i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
    var td = tds[i];
    var numbers = td.innerHTML.split('\\');
    td.innerHTML = `
        <span style="color:` + color1 + `">` + numbers[0] + `</span> 
        \\
        <span style="color:` + color2 + `">` + numbers[1] + `</span>
    `;
};
```

This code iterates through your `td` elements and parses out each number that is already in the cell, then inserts `span` elements in place of each number, with the `span`'s being colored using CSS.

Of course, if you have more `td` elements on the page besides the ones you need to manipulate, you'll need to be more specific with the selector.

Comment: I guess this answer assumes that I will insert data into `<td>`, correct? The data is already there. I just need to color it.

Comment: yes, it assumes the data will already be there.  this code just manipulates what is already there.  edited the answer for more clarification.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see, I missed it. The thing is that colors are defined dynamically as well (I did not include it in my question for simplicity). Anyway, I will try to incorporate your answer and reply here if it worked out.

Comment: dynamic colors shouldn't be too hard to incorporate, I added a simple addition to my answer that would get you started

Comment: Take a look at my Edit #2. I added a snippet of code. I am currently coloring the entire cell as you can see. My head is literally exploding right now, I will work on it tomorrow, but if you can incorporate your code into what I posted - it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is an awesome question.

The idea is to split the string by backslash and then wrap it with specific tag (contain a style).

Here is the example:

```
$('table td').each(function() {
  var str = $(this).html();
  var arr = str.split("\\");
  var el1 = '<span class="green">' + arr[0] + '</span>';
  var el2 = '<span class="red">' + arr[1] + '</span>';
  // Replace current column
  $(this).html(el1 + '\\' + el2);
});
```

And you can write a simple CSS style:

```
.green {
  color: green;
}
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

For the example result, just go here https://jsfiddle.net/ngekoding/Lmjpx014/10/

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try nested `for` loops, to hit each cell, and replace the text with added `span` tags that can color the text separately. I made sure this works and it **definitely** works for me:

```
<!--This Is The Demo Table, Fake Values and different slashes were used to display different results -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>red/blue</td>
        <td>blue\green</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hello\pink</td>
        <td>bad\\yellow</td>
        <td>hello\bye</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--The Actual JS Starts Here-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //GLOBAL VARS
    //This one represents all TR Tags in the document
    var tr = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    //For all TR Tags, do...
    for (var i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        //Create a Variable, representing all TD Tags inside current TR tag being scanned
        var nestedTD = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
        //For All TD Tags Inside Current TR Tag, do...
        for (var j = 0; j < nestedTD.length; j++) {
            //If The InnerHTML Of Each Tag Contains the "\" Character...
            if (nestedTD[j].innerHTML.includes("\\")) {
                //Then Split The InnerHTML Value Based on "\" (It returns array with ["text", "", "text"])
                var splitContentList = nestedTD[j].innerHTML.split("\\");
                //Replace the InnerHTML with a green and a red span tag, wrapping the texts
                nestedTD[j].innerHTML = "<span style='color: green;'>" + String(splitContentList[0]) + "</span>" + "\\" + "<span style='color: red;'>" + String(splitContentList[2]) + "</span>";
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This code took me a lot of effort, please don't hate on its conventions!!
I really hope this helps!